# Flask not getting cookies

Tags: python, flask, cookies, backend

I'm making backend for my website and it requires flask setting cookies. When I set the cookies, it works fine, but when I try to get them with `request.cookies.get('name')` it returns None. I tried just returning `request.cookies` and all that was there was my GA cookies, not the one that I set. Am I doing something wrong? Here's my code:

```py
@app.route("/setcookie", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def setcookie():
    resp = make_response(render_template("index.html"))
    resp.set_cookie("authToken", "testestestestestestes", max_age=1)
    return resp

@app.route("/getcookie", methods=["GET" ,"POST"])
def getcookie():
    return request.cookies
```

index.html form:

```html
<form action="/setcookie" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Set</button>
</form>
<form action="/getcookie" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Get</button>
</form>
```

I compared the GA cookies to the cookies that I set and the only difference was the name and value so that confuses me even more. I also don't need to do anything with them on the frontend, they only need to be read by flask. Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `max_age` to `1` second, your cookie just gets expired, try increasing `max_age` value

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I thought max_age represented days? Do you know what unit of time it does represent?

Comment: Seconds, see Flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/